# Why is "lysergic acid diethylamide" abbreviated to "LSD" instead of "LAD"?

Tags: abbreviations

What's the point? lalala need to stretch out

Comment: What's the point? You could have used your lala letters to tell us what research you had carried out on your own behalf to demonstrate that you didn't think this was a 'google for me' service? http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask I mean, the third paragraph of the LSD wiki page is hardly difficult to find.

Comment: Almost every question can be googled, or libraried, or some kind. What does you site stand for in such a case? Or you may know more than books and internet? I doubt it. That's utter and total absurd, I consider

Comment: *youR, certainly

Comment: The website is here for people who want to understand the finer points of the language, who cannot find the answer to their questions in a dictionary or in Wikipedia. Yes, nearly everything is Googleable, but some things are harder to find than others. The user below, who should know better by now, answered by Googling. Something which most adults using the Internet are capable of doing for themselves. It's when you don't immediately find an answer, or after several minutes or hours of searching,  that you come here and ask.

Comment: Absurd you may find it @SergeyZolotarev but it is how this site works as a tour of the Help center would explain. http://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - despite the tone, users are trying to help you understand how the site works. Next time you post a question, I hope you will, please add some preliminary research. Welcome to ELU.

Comment: @Josh I wonder, how you'd determined the tone of a WRITTEN text. You guys up there are ones of inconceivable talents, apparently. Love you boyos, believe we shall be friends

Comment: To be honest I really can't get what questions are quite suitable for such a scientific public. No offense

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I could get away with questions like that here, but I had to create like a dozen accounts on StackOverflow to keep asking *much* better questions there (which, still, attracted an occasional downvote tipping the average score below a certain threshold once every few months). Folks, I meant no offence. Sorry, if it was taken as a sign of disrespect for your platform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysergic_acid_diethylamide.) derives from the original German noun:

> LSD was first made by Albert Hofmann in Switzerland in 1938 from ergotamine, a chemical from the fungus ergot. The laboratory name for the compound was the acronym for the German "***Lyserg-säure-diäthylamid***", followed by a sequential number: LSD-25.

Wikipedia

[LSD: A Short History](http://www.drugfreeworld.org/drugfacts/lsd/a-short-history.html):

> - Because of its similarity to a chemical present in the brain and its similarity in effects to certain aspects of psychosis, ***LSD was used in experiments by psychiatrists through the 1940s, ’50s and ’60s***.
> - ***LSD was popularized in the 1960s by individuals such as psychologist Timothy Leary, who encouraged American students to “turn on, tune in, and drop out.”*** This created an entire counterculture of drug abuse and spread the drug from America to the United Kingdom and the rest of Europe. Even today, use of LSD in the United Kingdom is significantly higher than in other parts of the world.